# VisualBasic to Linq expression tree

Tags: .net, linq, expression-trees, workflow-foundation-4

Does anyone of you know whether there is any (reliable) way to convert a Visual Basic (textual) expression to a Linq expression-tree?
On the MS Library, there is an explicit reference to this argument, but it seems hidden to the user (or at least I guess so).

Here is the page about Workflow Activities:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358749.aspx

At the middle of the page they write:

*At run time, Visual Basic expressions are compiled into LINQ expressions. ...*

My deal is having a somewhat (stateless) function, so that (in C# syntax):

```
Expression expr = VisualBasicToLinqExpr("New Random().Next(1, 101)");
```

Any idea?
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the System.CodeDom namespace to compile any visual basic expression into executable code, even an LINQ statement.

Comment: It should be working, but it pollutes the domain with ton of assemblies. Thanks anyway.